# Error: You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry and strange character in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, stack

I'm drafting a paper and got a error:
[image: error]

In bibliography there is a strange character ".." after "Proceedings":

Files:

dados-seminario.tex:

```
\autor{Seu Nome Completo}
\codigoautor{SC XXXXX}

\titulo{Título Completo do Trabalho de Dissertação}

\dataapresentacao{31}{Fevereiro}{2016}

\area{Área de Concentração da Proposta de Dissertação}
\linha{Linha de Pesquisa da Proposta de Dissertação}

\orientador{Nome Completo do Orientador}{D}

\postoorientador{Ten Cel}

\coorientador{Nome Completo do Co-orientador}{P}
\coord{Nome Completo do Coordenador}{P}

\postocoord{Cel}


\chefe{Nome Completo do Chefe da SE/8}

\postochefe{Cel}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{seminario}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    headheight=0mm,
    headsep=0mm,
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATand}{;}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATetal}{et~al.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{%
  \ifNAT@swa\expandafter\MakeUppercase
  \else\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATand}{ e}\expandafter\@firstofone\fi{{\NAT@up #1}}%
}
\makeatother

\graphicspath{{./img/}}


\begin{document}

\include{dados-seminario}

\makecapa
\maketitle

\parindent 0.75cm

\include{secao-02}


\bibliographystyle{seminario}
\bibliography{refs}

\preparatitulos
\makeassinaturas
\label{theend}
\end{document}
```

secao-02.tex:

```
\chapter{Introdu\c{c}\~{a}o}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis \citep{zargar2013survey}. 
. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam \citep{zargar2013survey}.. 

\section{Objetivo}
 nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna\cite{rai2016survey}

\section{Problemas de Pesquisa}
, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl \citep{zargar2013survey}.
\section{Contribuições Esperadas}
```

seminario.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{seminario}
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagetrue
\newif\if@append
\@appendfalse
\newif\if@appendformat
\@appendformatfalse
\newif\if@annexformat
\@annexformatfalse
\newif\if@abrevia
\@abreviafalse
\newif\if@simbo
\@simbofalse

\DeclareOption{a4paper}        {\setlength\paperheight{297mm} \setlength\paperwidth{210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}        {\setlength\paperheight{210mm} \setlength\paperwidth{148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}        {\setlength\paperheight{250mm} \setlength\paperwidth{176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}    {\setlength\paperheight{11in} \setlength\paperwidth{8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}     {\setlength\paperheight{14in} \setlength\paperwidth{8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper} {\setlength\paperheight{10.5in} \setlength\paperwidth{7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}      {\setlength\@tempdima{\paperheight} \setlength\paperheight{\paperwidth} \setlength\paperwidth{\@tempdima}}
\DeclareOption{titlepage}      {\@titlepagetrue}
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}

\newif\if@restonecol
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}


\newif\if@openright
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}


\DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}} % Posicionar a numeração das equações à esquerda
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}} % Posicionar as equações a uma indentação fixa da margem esquerda

\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\DeclareOption{openright}{\@openrighttrue}
\DeclareOption{openany}{\@openrightfalse}


\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage,onecolumn,final,openany}
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301

\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}


\if@twoside
    \def\ps@headings{%
        \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
        \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
        \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
        \let\@mkboth\markboth
        \def\chaptermark##1{%
            \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi
            ##1}}{}}%
        \def\sectionmark##1{%
            \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@ \thesection. \ \fi
        ##1}}}}
\else
    \def\ps@headings{%
        \let\@oddfoot\@empty
        \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
        \let\@mkboth\markboth
        \def\chaptermark##1{%
            \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi
            ##1}}}}
\fi

\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble}
\def\ssp{\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\large\normalsize}
\def\dsp{\def\baselinestretch{1.37}\large\normalsize}


\newcommand*\chaptermark[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {chapter}
\newcounter {section}[chapter]
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]

\renewcommand\thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand\thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection .\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}

\newcommand\nomecapitulo{CAP{\'I}TULO}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\nomecapitulo}

\newcommand\part{
    \if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \if@twocolumn \onecolumn \@tempswatrue \else \@tempswafalse \fi
    \null\vfil
    \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
        \refstepcounter{part}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{} {
        \centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
            \huge\bfseries \nomeparte~\thepart
            \par
            \vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \Huge \bfseries #2\par}
    \@endpart}

\def\@spart#1{
    {  \centering
       \interlinepenalty \@M
       \normalfont
       \Huge \bfseries #1\par}
    \@endpart}

\def\@endpart{
    \vfil\newpage
    \if@twoside
        \null
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \newpage
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
        \twocolumn
    \fi}

\newcommand\chapter{
    \if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindenttrue
    \dsp
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@append \refstepcounter{section} \else \refstepcounter{chapter} \fi%
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
        {
            \def\\{ }%
            \if@append
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection\ }\uppercase{\@chapapp \space \@arabic\c@section}:\space#1}
            \else
                \if@appendformat
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter\ }\textbf\nomeindiceapendice}
                \else
                    \if@annexformat
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter\ }\textbf\nomeindiceanexo}
                    \else
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter\ }\bf#1}
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        }%
    \else
        {
            \def\\{ }  % allow \\ in title
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
        }%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}] \else \@makechapterhead{#2} \@afterheading \fi}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {
        \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \if@append 
%            \thesection \space \@chapapp \space \@arabic\c@section: \space \MakeUppercase{#1} \par \nobreak% 
            \@chapapp \space \@arabic\c@section: \space \MakeUppercase{#1} \par \nobreak% 
        \else 
            \bfseries \thechapter \space \MakeUppercase{#1} \par \nobreak%
        \fi
            \vskip 3\baselineskip
        \dsp
    }}

\def\@schapter#1{
    \if@twocolumn
        \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \else
        \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
        \@afterheading
    \fi}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
    \parindent \z@ 
    \normalfont
    \hbox to\textwidth{\bfseries \hfill
    \MakeUppercase{#1}\hfill}
    \nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
    \dsp}

\newcommand\section{
    \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
        {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
        {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
        {\normalfont\MakeUppercase}}

\newcommand\subsection{
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
    {\normalfont\MakeUppercase}}

\newcommand\subsubsection{
    \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\MakeUppercase}}

\newcommand\paragraph{
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}
    {-1em}
    {\normalfont\normalsize}}

\newcommand\subparagraph{
    \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize}}


\if@twocolumn \setlength\leftmargini  {2em} \else \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em} \fi

\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}

\if@twocolumn \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em} \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em} \else \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em} \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em} \fi

\setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
\@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
\@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty

\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\newcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\newcommand\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii})}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}

\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}

\newenvironment{description}
    {\list{}{
        \labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
    {\endlist}

\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep \normalfont\bfseries #1}



\newenvironment{verse}
    {\let\\\@centercr
     \list{}{
        \itemsep      \z@
        \itemindent   -1.5em%
        \listparindent\itemindent
        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
     \item\relax}
    {\endlist}

\newenvironment{quotation}
    {\list{}{
        \listparindent 1.5em%
        \itemindent    \listparindent
        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
     \item\relax}
    {\endlist}

\newenvironment{quote}
    {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin} \item\relax}
    {\endlist}


\newcounter{teorema}[chapter]
\newenvironment{thm}[1][]{\refstepcounter{teorema}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Teorema~\theteorema. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}

\newcounter{problema}[chapter]
\newenvironment{probl}[1][]{\refstepcounter{problema}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Problema~\theproblema. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}

\newcounter{questao}[chapter]
\newenvironment{qpesq}[1][]{\refstepcounter{questao}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Quest\~{a}o de Pesquisa~\thequestao. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}

\newcounter{hipotese}[chapter]
\newenvironment{hipo}[1][]{\refstepcounter{hipotese}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Hip\'{o}tese~\thehipotese. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}

\newcounter{proposicao}[chapter]
\newenvironment{prop}[1][]{\refstepcounter{proposicao}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Proposi\c{c}\~{a}o~\theproposicao. #1} \rmfamily}

\newcounter{definicao}[chapter]
\newenvironment{defn}[1][]{\refstepcounter{definicao}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Defini\c{c}\~{a}o~\thedefinicao. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}

\newcounter{exemplo}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exmp}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exemplo}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Exemplo~\theexemplo. #1} \rmfamily}

\newcounter{nota}[chapter]
\newenvironment{nota}[1][]{\refstepcounter{nota}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Nota~\thenota. #1} \rmfamily}

\newcounter{tarefaok}[chapter]
\newenvironment{tarefac}[1][]{\refstepcounter{tarefaok}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Tarefa~\thetarefaok. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}

\newcounter{tarefanok}[chapter]
\newenvironment{tarefanc}[1][]{\refstepcounter{tarefanok}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Tarefa~\thetarefanok. #1} \rmfamily\itshape}


\@addtoreset {equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand\theequation
  {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}


\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}

\newcommand\nomefigura{FIG.}
\newcommand\nometabela{TAB.}

\newcounter{figure}[chapter]
\renewcommand \thefigure {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\nomefigura~\thefigure}
\newenvironment{figure}
    {\ssp\@float{figure}}
    {\end@float\dsp}
\newenvironment{figure*}
    {\ssp\@dblfloat{figure}}
    {\end@dblfloat\dsp}

\newcounter{table}[chapter]
\renewcommand \thetable {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{\nometabela~\thetable}
\newenvironment{table}
    {\ssp\@float{table}}
    {\end@float\dsp}
\newenvironment{table*}
    {\ssp\@dblfloat{table}}
    {\end@dblfloat\dsp}


\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\newlength\belowcaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        #1: #2\par
    \else
        \global \@minipagefalse
        \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip}



\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}



\def\autor#1{\gdef\@autor{#1}}
\def\codigoautor#1{\gdef\@codigoautor{#1}}
\def\postoautor#1{\gdef\@postoautor{#1}}

\def\titulo#1{\gdef\@titulo{#1}}
\def\titantigo#1{\gdef\@titantigo{#1}}
\def\dataapresentacao#1#2#3{\gdef\@dia{#1} \gdef\@mes{#2} \gdef\@ano{#3}}

\def\area#1{\gdef\@area{#1}}
\def\linha#1{\gdef\@linha{#1}}

\def\orientador#1#2{\gdef\@orientador{#1} \gdef\@titorientador{#2}}
\def\postoorientador#1{\gdef\@postoorientador{#1}}
\gdef\@titA{}

\def\coorientador#1#2{\gdef\@coorientador{#1} \gdef\@titcoorientador{#2}}
\def\postocoorientador#1{\gdef\@postocoorientador{#1}}
\gdef\@titB{}

\def\coord#1#2{\gdef\@coord{#1} \gdef\@titcoord{#2}}
\def\postocoord#1{\gdef\@postocoord{#1}}
\gdef\@titC{}

\def\chefe#1{\gdef\@chefe{#1}}
\def\postochefe#1{\gdef\@postochefe{#1}}


\newcommand\preparatitulos{
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{P}=0\gdef\@titA{Ph.D.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{D}=0\gdef\@titA{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{DC}=0\gdef\@titA{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{D.C.}=0\gdef\@titA{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{D.C}=0\gdef\@titA{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{DC.}=0\gdef\@titA{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titorientador}{}=0\else\gdef\@titA{\@titorientador}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi

    \ifdefined \@coorientador
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{P}=0\edef\@titB{Ph.D.}
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{D}=0\edef\@titB{D.Sc.}
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{DC}=0\edef\@titB{D.Sc.}
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{D.C.}=0\edef\@titB{D.Sc.}
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{D.C}=0\edef\@titB{D.Sc.}
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{DC.}=0\edef\@titB{D.Sc.}
        \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoorientador}{}=0\else\edef\@titB{\@titcoorientador}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \fi

    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{P}=0\gdef\@titC{Ph.D.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{D}=0\gdef\@titC{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{DC}=0\gdef\@titC{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{D.C.}=0\gdef\@titC{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{D.C}=0\gdef\@titC{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{DC.}=0\gdef\@titC{D.Sc.}
    \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@titcoord}{}=0\else\gdef\@titC{\@titcoord}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}



\newcommand\makecapa{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent
    \begin{center}

        \begin{large}
            \textbf{MINIST\'{E}RIO DA DEFESA\\}
            \textbf{EX\'{E}RCITO BRASILEIRO\\}
            \textbf{DEPARTAMENTO DE CI\^{E}NCIA E TECNOLOGIA\\}
            \textbf{INSTITUTO MILITAR DE ENGENHARIA\\}
            \textbf{CURSO DE MESTRADO EM SISTEMAS E COMPUTA\c{C}\~{A}O}

            \vspace{2cm}
            \textbf{RELAT\'{O}RIO DE ACOMPANHAMENTO DE TRABALHO DE DISSERTA\c{C}\~{A}O DE MESTRADO}

            \vspace{4.5cm}
            \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@autor}}

            \vspace{4.5cm}
            \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@titulo}}

            \vspace{5cm}
            \textbf{Rio de Janeiro\\}
            \textbf{\@ano}
        \end{large}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
}



\newcommand\maketitle{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \chapter{T\'{i}tulo do Trabalho de Disserta\c{c}\~{a}o}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \textbf{T\'{i}tulo Atual do Trabalho de Disserta\c{c}\~{a}o:}\\
            \@titulo \\

            \ifdefined \@titantigo
                \vspace{0.7cm}
                \textbf{T\'{i}tulo Anterior do Trabalho de Disserta\c{c}\~{a}o:}\\
                \@titantigo \\
            \fi

            \vspace{0.7cm}
            \textbf{\'{A}rea de Concentra\c{c}\~{a}o:}\\
            \@area \\

            \vspace{0.7cm}
            \textbf{Linha de Pesquisa:}\\
            \@linha \\
        \end{flushleft}
    \newpage
}



\newcommand\nomebibliografia{REFER\^ENCIAS BIBLIOGR\'AFICAS}

\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}

\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1] {}

\newenvironment{thethesisbibliography}[1] {
    \chapter{
        \nomebibliografia
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\nomebibliografia}{\MakeUppercase\nomebibliografia}
    }
    \ssp \list{}{}
} {\def\@noitemerr {\@latex@warning{Empty `thethesisbibliography' environment}} \endlist}

\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\let\@openbib@code\@empty

\renewenvironment{thethesisbibliography}[1] {
    \chapter{
        \nomebibliografia
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\nomebibliografia}{\MakeUppercase\nomebibliografia}
    }
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}} {
        \settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}
        \leftmargin=20pt
        \itemindent=-20pt
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}
    }
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000
    \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m
} {\def\@noitemerr {\@latex@warning{Empty `thethesisbibliography' environment}} \endlist}


\def\@approvalspace{2cm}
\newcommand\makeassinaturas{
    \newpage
    \begingroup
        \noindent
        \vspace{5mm}
        \begin{center}

            $\:\overline{\makebox[10cm][c]{\ifdefined \@postoautor {\@postoautor}\fi ~{\@autor} {(\@codigoautor)}}}\:$ \\
            Aluno\\
            \vspace{\@approvalspace}

            $\:\overline{\makebox[10cm][c]{\ifdefined \@postoorientador {\@postoorientador}\fi ~{\@orientador,}~{\@titA}}}\:$ \\
            Orientador\\
            \vspace{\@approvalspace}

            \ifdefined \@coorientador
                $\:\overline{\makebox[10cm][c]{\ifdefined \@postocoorientador {\@postocoorientador}\fi ~{\@coorientador,}~{\@titB}}}\:$ \\
                Co-orientador\\
                \vspace{\@approvalspace}
            \fi

            $\:\overline{\makebox[10cm][c]{\ifdefined \@postocoord {\@postocoord}\fi ~{\@coord,}~{\@titC}}}\:$ \\
            Coordenador de P\'{o}s-gradua\c{c}\~{a}o\\
        \end{center}

        \vspace{\@approvalspace}
        \noindent
        Declaro que o presente Relat\'{o}rio de Acompanhamento de Trabalho de Disserta\c{c}\~{a}o foi apresentado segundo as NICPG/IME em \@dia \:de\:\@mes \:de\:\@ano.

        \vspace{\@approvalspace}
        \begin{center}
            $\:\overline{\makebox[10cm][c]{\ifdefined \@postochefe {\@postochefe}\fi ~{\@chefe}}}\:$ \\
            CHEFE da SE/8\\
        \end{center}

    \endgroup
    \newpage
}


\setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
\setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\if@twoside \else \raggedbottom \fi
\if@twocolumn \twocolumn \sloppy \flushbottom \else \onecolumn \fi

\newenvironment{frontmatter} {
    \if@twocolumn \@restonecolfalse \else \@restonecoltrue \fi
    \columnseprule \z@
    \columnsep 35\p@
    \onecolumn
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
} {\newpage}
\endinput
```

refs.bib :

```
@article{zargar2013survey,
  title={A survey of defense mechanisms against distributed denial of service (DDoS) flooding attacks},
  author={Zargar, Saman Taghavi and Joshi, James and Tipper, David},
  journal={IEEE Communications Surveys \& Tutorials},
  volume={15},
  number={4},
  pages={2046--2069},
  year={2013},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{rai2016survey,
  title={Survey on Recent DDoS Mitigation Techniques and Comparative Analysis},
  author={Rai, Ankur and Challa, Rama Krishna},
  booktitle={Computational Intelligence \& Communication Technology (CICT), 2016 Second International Conference on},
  edition = {1},
  pages={96-101},
  year={2016},
  type = {intl},
  organization={IEEE},
  publisher = {IEEE}

}
```

seminario.bst: https://ufile.io/p50am

Could someone help?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob: done!

Comment: Welcome! Can you try opening up a **new** document, with documentclass `article`, citing any one of the problematic entries, like `zargar2013survey`, and report back if the problem persists? Use the `seminario.bst` bib style and don't load any unnecessary packages.

Comment: @Troy: I will do it and report back! thanks

Comment: @Troy:
I edited the question with the new trial:  
 
All files used:  https://ufile.io/d3t4a
image of strange character:http://imgur.com/a/NAUaO

Comment: @EdS Thanks for doing so! Check line 921 of your bst file. `output.ckeck` should be `output.check`.

Comment: @Troy: Thanks. I will check and repory back!

Comment: @Troy: line 920 and line 921, right?

Comment: @Troy:

After changing lines 920 and 921 in seminario.bst

output.ckeck to output.check:

error: http://imgur.com/a/H9F4U

nothing changed: http://imgur.com/a/Qe5dW

Comment: @EdS The log error says that `zargar2013survey` has a repeated entry in your bib file. ie. there are two bib entries with the same key `zargar2013survey`. Do a search through your bib file, and delete the repeated entry.

Comment: If the problem still persists, please do copy the code that you are testing with (i.e. the article documentclass thing I mentioned earlier) here so that we can copy, paste and compile it to reproduce the problem on our systems. As it stands, your question is not of much use to others as (i) there was a minor error in your custom bst file, and (ii) repeated entry in your bib file, both of which are provided in an external link (and will eventually become invalid)

Comment: @Troy: I copied the code, but "seminario.bst" is very long. It is not possible copy and paste "seminario.bst"  in the question!

Comment: @EdS Is the problem resolved? Again, we don't need `main.tex`, a simple **minimal** document (with article documentclass, *not* the seminario.cls -- this class is not relevant to your question) will do.

Comment: @Troy: problem not resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following test file for your bibliography

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    headheight=0mm,
    headsep=0mm,
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATand}{;}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATetal}{et~al.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{%
  \ifNAT@swa\expandafter\MakeUppercase
  \else\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATand}{ e}\expandafter\@firstofone\fi{{\NAT@up #1}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % seminario plainnat
\bibliography{ref1} % refs ref1

\end{document}
```

I can compile without errors. Please see that I used style `plainnat` and the following bib file `ref1.bib`:

```
@article{boteanu2013comprehensive,
  title={A comprehensive study of queue management as a DoS countermeasure},
  author={Boteanu, Daniel and Fernandez, Jos{\'e} M},
  journal={International journal of information security},
  volume={12},
  number={5},
  pages={347--382},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Springer},
}
```

If I change the bibliography style to `seminario.bst` the error you have occours.  For me means that that your style `seminario.bst` is faulty.

Please contact the creator of that style/class to correct that style. 
Sorry, I can not help you to find the errors inside that file ...